How to assert if an object has an ancestor of another object in when clause?
So as the title suggests I need to check if an object is inherited from a given class.
I've written a function (code snippet below) which checks if an item is an instance of a given class, but I want to check if it is a descendant of the KView class, not a direct child (as in I want it to check it's ancestors until it find KView or reaches the root ancestor).
Is it possible in Kotlin and if it is, can I use it in a when clause?
when (item) {
    is KRecyclerView -> item.assertWithCondition { isVisibleAndEnabled() }
    is KView -> item.assertWithCondition { isVisibleAndEnabled() }
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Item has wrong type")
}


is KView already does that. Can you show a [mre] showing why that is not the case?

@Sweeper I'm terribly sorry, I just went all the way to the base view we're using in the project and realized it inherits KDSLView instead of KView... I don't know why I haven't realized it before even though I was working with the function for the whole day now. I just added an is KDSLView<*> ->  assertion and function works just fine now

this function actually works (posting full function just in case anybody else would need it), it's just that I checked if an item is inherited from a wrong ancestor, duh
fun scrollForward(steps: Int = 30): Boolean = try {
        getUiScrollable().scrollForward(steps)
    } catch (e: UiObjectNotFoundException) {
        false
    }

private fun conditionalAssertion(assert: () -> Unit) =
        try {
            assert()
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (e is NullPointerException || e is NoMatchingViewException) {
                false
            } else {
                throw e
            }
        }

fun <K : BaseAssertions> K.assertWithCondition(assertion: K.() -> Unit): Boolean =
        conditionalAssertion { assertion() }

fun <T>RecyclerActions.scrollToFirstItemFromTop(item: T, shouldExist: Boolean = true) {
        run breaking@{
            repeat(3) {
                ScreenScrollerHelper.scrollForward(100)
                val isElementFound =
                    when (item) {
                        is KRecyclerView -> item.assertWithCondition { isVisibleAndEnabled() }
                        is KView -> item.assertWithCondition { isVisibleAndEnabled() }
                        is KDSLView<*> -> item.assertWithCondition { isVisibleAndEnabled() }
                        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Item has wrong type")
                    }
                if (isElementFound || !shouldExist) {
                    return@breaking
                }
            }
        }
    }


Thanks for the follow-up.
